# How to debug this error 'The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.'?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to work with forms in laravel but I keep getting this error

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException The GET method is not supported for this
>   route. Supported methods: POST.

I have tried so many ways to solve it but ain't solving it

Here my model

**create_posts_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

**post.php**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model {
    protected $fillable = ['caption', 'image'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Controller PostsController

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('posts.create');
    }


    public function store(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        ]);

        Post::create($request->input());

        dd($request->all());
    }
}
```

**Routes web.php**

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
j|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store')->name('p.store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

Blade file:

```
<div class="container"> <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> @csrf
```

Kindly Help me, I've been stack for 3 days because of that above error .

In the browser I have this

```
 protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others, $method)
    {
        throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException(
            $others,
            sprintf(
                'The %s method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: %s.',
                $method,
                implode(', ', $others)
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `form` from where you are calling the post route?

Comment: how you are calling the post route? 
show code of form

Comment: Please check your form action and method.

Comment: Here it it is  <div class="container">
        <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf

Comment: @Jimmyjbk change your form code to this  `<form action="{{route('p.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> @csrf `

Comment: Have you tried placing `{{ method_field('POST') }}` after `<form action="{{route('p.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: According to your comment, your `<form>` appears to be correct. Could you provide the `Envoirement Details` that you see on the Whoops! page? They can be found int the bottom right corner.

I assume that you have a html form from which you acces your PostsController. Your tag should look something like this: `<form action="{{route('p.store')}}" method="post"`. You probably have `method="get"`. If so, change the method to post, that should work.

Comment: Here it is in the whoops page    "/Users/macair13/freeCodeGram/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php"

Comment: I have everything the way you told me